# Why does code first/EF use 'nvarchar(4000)' for strings in the raw SQL command?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Essentially I have a table with zip codes in it. The zipcode field is defined as 'char(5)'. I'm using code first, so I've put these attributes on my ZipCode property:

```
[Key, Column( Order = 0, TypeName = "nchar"), StringLength(5)]
public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

Now if I query against this in EF:

```
var zc = db.ZipCodes.FirstOrDefault(zip => zip.ZipCode == "12345");
```

The generated SQL uses nvarchar(4000) to inject the parameters. Huh? Is it because "12345" is technically a string of unknown length? Shouldn't EF be smart enough to just use the proper "nchar(5)" when querying that table?

I ask because the nvarchar(4000) query takes half a second whereas the properly-scoped query is much faster (and less reads).

Any assistance/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: did you drop and recreate the database after you added the attributes to your entities?

Comment: This is against an existing database, and I'm not letting Code First re-gen it. The existing database is definitely char(5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to take advantage of auto parameterization.  The following article explains the general concept as well as why specifically nvarchar(4000) is used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx

Comment: Hrm, thanks for the answer. But I guess it still doesn't answer why EF works this way. Wouldn't it be more efficient to use the same data types when generating queries?

Comment: "Another good habit to get into for string-based data types is to always specify the length of the parameter. This value should be the length of the field in the SQL predicate that uses the parameter, or the maximum string length (4,000 for NVARCHAR, 8,000 for VARCHAR), not the length of the string itself. SQL Server autoparameterization always assumes the maximum string length..." - it seems to me that this informs why they would make the decision.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I guess it's fine for the article to say that, but the performance is definitely different between the two queries. It's just very odd that the EF team would choose to go a less-performant route. Oh well, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) attribute?  [This article](http://prashantbrall.wordpress.com/2011/04/) gives a decent summary of how the various data annotation attributes are interpreted by EF.

Comment: I'll try using MaxLength, thanks. I also was using StringLength and had the same question as the originator of this question. Thanks.

Comment: MaxLength didn't work for me, may be because I'm setting attributes using MetaDataClass ? 
 `code` public partial class OperatorMetadata
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        [StringLength(6)]
        [MaxLength(6)]
        public String OpCode { get; set; }