# Why does Entity Framework generate large parameters? How can they be reduced?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

In a very simple db query:

```
_service.GetAll<Visitor>().Any(r => r.EmailAddress == email)
```

when tracing this using Glimpse, it shows a parameter `@p__linq__0` of Type `String` and Size `4000` being passed to the database. The following SQL is generated:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Visitor] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[VisitorType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[EmailAddress] = 'test@test.com' /* @p__linq__0 */) OR (([Extent2].[EmailAddress] IS NULL) AND ('test@test.com' /* @p__linq__0 */ IS NULL))
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

This seems quite wasteful, when a MaxLength of 254 has been defined.

Can anyone explain why this is? And how I can change the parameter size?

**UPDATE**

The following similar question also doesn't give a solution on how to change this default behaviour:
[Why does code first/EF use 'nvarchar(4000)' for strings in the raw SQL command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538746/why-does-code-first-ef-use-nvarchar4000-for-strings-in-the-raw-sql-command)

From a db optimization point of view it makes sense, however when trying to reduce the amount data transferred to mobile clients in a slow network environment, it doesn't make sense to increase every string parameter to 4000 bytes.

Comment: where do you see 4000?

Comment: using Glimpse I see the parameter size

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does code first/EF use 'nvarchar(4000)' for strings in the raw SQL command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538746/why-does-code-first-ef-use-nvarchar4000-for-strings-in-the-raw-sql-command)

Comment: I don’t know SQL TDS protocol details, but the datatype `*VARCHAR()` only stores the actual used length, so I assume TDS would do the same. There’s no data saving in having a lower number because it would only send the number of bytes necessary to store the string. Now, for `*CHAR()` types with padding at the end, it might send the value over the network with padding too.